# Bing api sample code

Tags: java

I use this sample code of bing api :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
public class bingSearch {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //--------------------------------------Bing search------------------------------
        String searchText = "swim";
        searchText = searchText.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        String accountKey="Your-AccountKEY";
        byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
        String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(  
                    "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27" + searchText + "%27&$top=50&$format=Atom");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);

     //  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(output);

              //  text.append(link + "\n\n\n");//Will print the google search links
            //}     
        } 

        conn.disconnect(); 

        int find = sb.indexOf("<d:Description");

        int total = find + 1000;

        System.out.println("Find index: " + find);
        System.out.println("Total index: " + total);
        sb.getChars(find+35, total, buffer, 0);

        String str = new String(buffer);

        int find2 = str.indexOf("</d:Description>");

        int total2 = find2 + 400;
        System.out.println("Find index: " + find);
        System.out.println("Total index: " + total);
        char[] buffer2 = new char[1024];

        str.getChars(0, find2, buffer2 , 0);
        String str2 = new String(buffer2);
        str2 = Jsoup.parse(str2).text();    
        System.out.println(str2);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }        
}
```

The out put is:

Output from Server ....

```
Find index: 1014
Total index: 2014
Find index: 1014
Total index: 2014
A computer is a general purpose device that can be programmed to carry out a finite set of arithmetic or logical operations. Since a sequence of operations can be ...
```

It show just one result, But I need more than one result.
Doing it with this code is possible? Or Is other substitute for this code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your call to Bing you are requesting the results as an [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) feed, and that's what you're getting back (38785 chars long for that particular query) and you really should treat it as an Atom feed and parse it in a more appropriate way.

The reason you only get one result in your code though is that you never seem to loop over the `sb` string containing the feed. If you really want to parse the feed this way you need to move to code after `conn.disconnect()` to a loop and use something like `sb.indexOf("<d:Description", int fromIndex)` to traverse the string increasing the fromIndex each time you find a new match.

But you really should treat the response from Bing like the xml-feed it is and parse it using some xml-library, for instance [Rome](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home).

Comment: @NargesSadri If you found the answer helpful feel free to upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new with java and bing live search. unfortunately I did not much understand about your answer. Is other bing api sample code that do it for me? I mean in the output the result be more than one?

Comment: @NargesSadri The result you get back from the query and assign to the `output` variable actually contains more than one result, but it's formatted as an XML document which you need to parse. You can get the result in the [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format if you change `format=Atom` to `format=json` in the URL, and that might be easier to parse, but in any case you need to parse the result to access the individual results. I'd suggest searching for something like **parse json java**. I can't really help you with the parsing as I don't know much about it myself.